# Ability to Modify Active Directory from Java and/or Spring Security on Linux

Tags: java, linux, spring-security, active-directory

I've been searching for a while now and while I can find a plethora of information on how to authenticate against an Active Directory server via Java and/or Spring on Linux, I've yet to be able to find any information on how to **WRITE** to an Active Directory server from Java and/or Spring on Linux.

When I say **WRITE**, I mean add/remove permissions, manage roles (groups), the ability to add/remove users to/from those groups, and add/remove group permissions.

I'm hoping that if there's no solution out there already, a custom/Mono app can handle the work.

Does anyone know of any API, library, or product that does this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spring LDAP](http://www.springsource.org/ldap) provides [LdapTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html) for all your LDAP needs. It has some precautions around AD, but it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used for years now, but if Active Directory is still some kind on slightly non-standard LDAP, try **JNDI**.

Answer (score 1):

AD is an LDAP server that implements LDAPv3 mostly, so you can access it in order to read and write using JNDI. JNDI allows you to access any "directory" service using "standard" API in Java. You should use a LDAP Java API that is more specific in order to write and get access to all LDAP operations.

We modify an LDAP server (Active Directory) from a Java Swing application using LDAP Java API, java.naming.ldap package and works fine.